# checking multiple conditions in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have below code:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
e = 5
if ((a == 1 and
     b == 2 and
     c == 4) or
     (d == 4  and e == 5)):
    print "Yeah, Working"
else:
    print "ooops"
```

Can be achieved same code  easy and  best way?

Comment: I like to save off the "pieces" into their own variables.  e.g. `is_valid = (a == 1 and b == 2 and c == 4)`, `has_some_atttribute = (d == 4 and e == 5)`, `if is_valid or has_some_attribute: ...`

Comment: Also, this is Python! Remove those redundant brackets after `if`, ie, `if(...)` -> `if ...`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a very personal answer, but I like to initalize some boolean before the `if` statement.
I find it more readable (because you can give some meaningful name to your variable), and I'm pretty sure the compiler can easily optimize it.

```
cond1 = a == 1 and b == 2 and c == 4
cond2 = d == 4 and e == 5
if cond1 or cond2:
    print("Yeah, working")
else:
    print("ooops")
```

Comment: The compiler can optimise it to what? Python is interpreted and has _very_ limited ability to optimise anything

Comment: @roganjosh Yea it might be a strong assumption, but python code is still compiled into bytecode before being interpreted. I was hoping this step is smart enough to not declare 2 variables only used in the `if` statement and "inline" the condition... but I might have been too confident here

Answer (score 10):

If you want to if condition to be clearer or better looking, you can do it like this:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
e = 5
if (a, b, c) == (1, 2, 4) or (d, e) == (4, 5):
    print "Yeah, Working"
else:
    print "ooops"
```